# In SQLite, Can we create one database for each user in an app?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, password-manager, sqlite-cipher

I have a project as graduation thesis. i have to write a password manager app. in this app, many users can create, login their account and manage their data such as facebook account, gmail, tiktok,... and required using SQLite Cipher to encrypt each user's data ( the key to encrypt data is hashed from user password)
So , how can i do for creating each database for each user?
The example,

- user A create his account: username A , password a12345. after A login, the database of A is A_db.db
- user B create his account: username B , password b12345. after B login, the database of b is B_db.db.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you *could* (technically) create a separate SQLite database for each user.  An SQLite database is just a file.  You give the filename when you open the DB.  Multiple files with different names is simple to implement.

But **probably** you don't need to.

On Android, it is assumed that there is only one user of that given device.  The Android platform (AFAIK) does not support multiple users / accounts.  So ... assuming that this SQLite database is on the Android user's device, your problem simply does not arise.

If the databases are on a server ... will, not much is achieved by holding a separate database for each user.  You can hold the information in one database: SQLite or something more robust / scalable.

The only case where it would make sense to have per-user SQLite databases for a password manager application is if this is if the app designed to run on an OS that supports multiple user accounts; e.g. Windows, Unix, Linux, Mac OS, etc.  Then you can just put the database in each user's home directory ... or something like that.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  i know that " On Android, it is assumed that there is only one user of that given device" . but my small project is like a demo app with some feature i listed.  the requirement of graduation thesis that i have to follow.  because data of user relate with being encrypted with separate key, i need to create each db per each user.  would you mind creating a demo code for me ? thank you

Comment: Surely you can find example code to create an SQLite database?  Me writing demo code for you is a waste of time if you can find it yourself.  Indeed, you should be able to do it yourself from just the information you can get by reading the documentation.

Comment: I don't like the idea of my passwords or sensitive data being stored on a server mixed in with other people's data in a single large DB table or collection. I also would like each user's data to be stored in separate files. This could give better security / privacy in case of coding errors, and potentially better performance due to storing all the user's data together on the filesystem, not scattered in a huge table mixed in with other users' data.

Comment: Well yea ... but that is a different issue.  The question is about whether you should have a separate database for each user, not different databases to hold sensitive and non-sensitive data.  (And it is generally a bad idea to store passwords in databases ... period.  It is better to use seeded hashes.  If that's not possible, encrypt them ... and ask yourself the hard questions about whether that is good enough.  You want something that doesn't rely solely on file system permissions (or obscurity) to protect the sensitive data if your server is hacked.)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a database per user. Each user will have it's own copy of the database in their platform (I guess you are planning to create an Android app from the tags). So, you must design the database so that each user will use its own copy independently of other users.

Comment: yes. i am planng to create an app with some requirements as i listed in my topic.  because it require to encrypt user data with their own key hashed from login password, i think i need to create each db per each user.